# Can't get rid of a wrapper element on my page

Tags: css, tags, wrapper

I've been trying to get rid of the thin gray strip that's in the middle of this page:
http://redesign.emdintegration.com/index.html

It seems to be related to the wrapper but I can't get it to disappear. Please help!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this line from your CSS...

```
#Content{
background: url(../images/content.gif) 0 100% repeat-x; /*Delete this line*/
}
```

I believe it is line 129 in style-v1.css

Comment: Thanks Dayle - I removed the reference to the background url, problem solved.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: @TaylorFrank can you mark as correct answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CSS for `#content`.  It has a background image of a gray bar and a child `<div>` element within has a padding of 10px.

Answer (score 0):

You have a padding of `10px` on the following:

`<div class="container_24" style="padding-top:10px">`

Remove the style, and the gray stripe will disappear.

If you can't edit the HTML, you can add the following CSS rule:

`.container_24 {padding-top: 0 !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

On your `#content` you have `background: url(../images/content.gif) 0 100% repeat-x;`
If you get rid of it, that should take care of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

look at your debugger. in class `.container_24`, add `padding-top:0px;`, and delete the inline styling. That should get rid of all top padding in that class.
Best practices indicate to use seperate stylesheet for all your styling, instead of dirty, messy inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

The background url for #content is the gray line. You might think it's an element, but it's an image being directed by CSS for a background image for the id="content" on the page. I imagine the section element is for the product boxes and #content is in relation to that.

You could alter the CSS to not load this (../images/content.gif) by simply adding display: none to that line on the style sheet [Line 129]

Try copying this in its place.

```
#content {
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
display: none;
}
```